# Website showing wrong characters for texts in other languages

Tags: character-encoding, web, special-characters

I have lots of texts stored in a database. This texts are in different languages (English, Japanese, Arabic, Korean, Chinese, Spanish...).

When I look in the database using phpMyAdmin, I can see all the characters perfectly, for each language. However, when I want to print on screen those texts using PHP, I get either the symbol � or just a bunch of ????????.

The collation encoding for all of the fields that hold the texts is the same: **utf8_general_ci**.

Also, I've set the encoding of the website to "utf8":

What can I do to see them right? I've tried **utf8_encode()** and **utf8_decode()**, but nothing, it just fixes some characters in Western languages, but does nothing in languages with different alphabets.

I won't need to show in one same page all of the different alphabets, but I will need to show 2 of them simultaneously (it's a language learning website).

Any clues on how can I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution was easy: set in PHP the encoding of the database to 'UTF8'. In my case, since I'm using CakePHP, in the database configuration I had to add **'encoding'=>'UTF8'